# Primes in arithmetic progression $\{p ~{\rm ∈~ prime}~|~p,p+30,p+60,p+90,p+120,p+150\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

I found many primes sequence with pattern like $Q=\{p ~{\rm ∈~ prime}~|~p,p+30,p+60,p+90,p+120,p+150\}$, is there exist infinite prime $p$ holds such sequence? Then the elements in set $~Q~$ are primes ( in arithmetic progression), such as when $p=541,2221,135151,279421, 10^{20}+3346371,10^{40}+503428698001$ (the two large primes are Peter's finding), .

Below tables include some findings:
[image]

This is another pattern $~{Q=\{p∈prime |p,p+12,p+24,p+36}\}$
[image]

Comment: This is a bit hard to follow, but it clearly isn't true that every integer in $\{p+30k\}_{k=0}^{\infty}$ is prime.  In particular, $p+30p$ is not prime.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: There are infinite many solutions , if Schinzel's hypothesis is true. I do not think that Green Tao establishes infinite many solutions of this special kind. It only tells us that we can get arbitary long arithmetic progressions containing only primes.

Comment: Also if you extend the sequence to a seventh term one of them is divisible by $7$.  Unless $p=7$ that one will be composite

Comment: Did you mean to omit $p + 150$?

Comment: Sorry, it is my typo error, p+180 is p+150, I edit my post right now.

Comment: A larger solution is $$p=10^{20}+3346371$$

Comment: It is quite large, thanks so much.  Schinzel's hypothesis is unsolved prolem, maybe it is possible to start from such special case {p is prime | p,p+30,p+60,p+90,p+120,p+150}

Comment: $$10^{40}+503428698001$$ is an even larger solution.

Comment: Thanks so much, how long does it take to search for such a large solution?

Comment: To find it took quite a while (some hours at least on my computer) , to verify (prove) the primes is however routine.

Comment: @lulu, anyway I appreciate your comments, the primes set $  \{p ~{\rm ∈~ prime}~|~p,p+30,p+60,p+90,p+120,p+150\}$ length is with fixed k=6. For primes set   $  \{p ~{\rm ∈~ prime}~|~p,p+12,p+24,p+36\}$ the set length k=4.